# BFS in time O(m) for a directed graph

Tags: breadth-first-search, graph-traversal

In an undirected graph the running time of BFS is O(m+n). Is it possible to get a running time of O(m) in a directed graph? (|V|=n, |E|=m)

Answer (score 0):

Generally, BFS runs in `O(V+E)` time on both directed AND undirected graphs. Imposing the restriction that the graph is directed does NOT allow us to reduce the runtime to `O(E)`.

However, if we know that the graph is directed and acyclic, ie it is a DAG, then BFS runs in `O(V)`. This is because if the graph is acyclic, then `E < V` and so the BFS runtime of `O(V+E) = O(V+V) = O(V)`.